# Openshift Jenkins compilation error

Tags: jenkins, openshift

I'm trying to run maven compile on jenkins Openshift cartridge, but I have this error:

```
 error: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
[ERROR]   (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
```

I guess that's a problem with the installed JDK.

How I can change the version of the JDK?

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

[image: image3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the job configuration I activate the parameterized execution option and select JDK7

[image]